# Opening multiple ports using Boost Asio libraries

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am a newbie for Boost Asio libraries, my requirement is to build a server, which should listen on 600 different ports asynchronously (TCP communication). Can someone suggest me a smart way to achieve this using Boost Asio. I have tried using echo server example provided at Boost Asio documentation but could not really understand much
      boost::asio::io_service io_service;

```
using namespace std; // For atoi.
for(long port=50000;port<=50600;port++)
{
    server s(io_service, port);
    io_service.run();
}
```

Can someone throw light on this?

Comment: 'my requirement is to build a server,which should listen on 600 different ports' - are you sure that this is what you want to do?

Comment: Yes Martin, its something todo with simulation devices and I have 600 simulation devices hence I would need separate connection for each device.

Comment: @user1229153 You can accept as many connections as you like with a single server on a single port.

Comment: @spencercw, but will it help me to have Asynchronous communication with all connections opened? I would really appreciate if you can provide me any handy link about this.

Comment: @user1229153 Absolutely. Blocking I/O is usually a bad idea (IMO), and certainly when you've got 600 simultaneous connections you want to do it asynchronously. Check out the [chat examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html). You can ignore the chat related stuff, but the concept of a server managing a number of sessions works nicely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `io_service` is responsible for handling all I/O that is assigned to it; you don't need to create a separate one for each port. For what you are trying to do you will need to create 600 separate server instances then call `io_service.run()`.

```
vector<shared_ptr<server> > servers;
for (uint16_t port = 50000; port != 50600; ++port)
{
    servers.push_back(shared_ptr<server>(new server(io_service, port)));
}
io_service.run();
```

Comment: Thanks Spencercw, I just have one more question, How can print the received data in binary format? I am receiving it in to one char buffer and hence _itoa is failiing.

Comment: @user1229153 That's easy enough to do with iostreams. Sorry for the bad formatting; I can't do multi-line in comments..
    `unsigned char buf[] = { '\xab', '\xcd', '\xef' };
    cout << hex << setfill('0');
    for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(buf); ++i)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(buf[i]);
    }
    cout << "\n";`
This will print out `abcdef`.

Comment: Thanks much @spencercw,I understand what you are doing here. I don't know whether my question makes sense or not, in my program server receives data from a client and it's receiving it in char* variable and when I try printing it's some ascii values. I wanted to see what information my client exactly sending. As given in Asio example  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length)  I am using the same.Sorry if the question is very trivial.

Comment: @user1229153 You can use the code I posted to print out your `char *` buffer. You will need to cast each byte to `unsigned char` before you cast it to `unsigned` otherwise it won't print properly. I.e., `static_cast<unsigned>(static_cast<unsigned char>(buf[i]))`. You can also just look at the memory directly in a debugger if you prefer.

Comment: Is there any way with boost libraries returning back to calling function just reading the data once? What I mean here is - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp in this example, can I come back to io_service.run() just after reading data sent by client do some functionality and go back to listen mode? rather than sitting in busy loop to hear from client? Any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: Move as much as you can into the event based architecture. You want to fire off `run()` then do everything else from within your event handlers. So when you read some data, in your `handle_read()` function you will do whatever you need to do with the data you have just received then set off another `async_read` before returning.

Comment: Thanks @spencercw, I understand what you mentioned.The problem what I am working on is little weird, here it is at abstract level- I have a simulator and which is provided with an API, in API I have functions like init, manage which will execute serially.When the code in these functions executes the process(simulator)attached to it will stop and control goes only when my API stops. Now, I have this as server and there is a client which polls the server for evry 20 secs. I should just get all the information from client and use that to work with simulator. /*Continued in next comment*/

Comment: Here in init function, I am calling a function to open certain ports to listen for clients, (simulator attached will be blocked this time), Since my io_service.run is running all the time the call never goes back to API and results blocking of simulator all the time. So, I just need to get the data and resume to calling function(which will enable my simulator) and again call should be in listen mode to get next set of 20 secs information. I know its not the place for spoon feeding, since I am new to C++ not sure how to achieve this. Any suggestions? thanks @spencercw

Comment: I would move your `run()` call into a separate thread so you've got one thread for I/O which spends most of its time blocked and another thread for your simulator. You need to be careful though if your simulator's API is not thread safe; if it's not you will need to take care of that yourself. If you need a threading library [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread.html) would be a good choice.

Comment: A second option would be to use polling, though this depends on how your simulator works. If the simulator is calling into your code on a regular basis you could use `io_service::poll()` instead of `io_service::run()`. `poll()` just takes care of any events that have happened since its last call. This would probably be a lot easier because you wouldn't have to worry about any threading issues.

Comment: Thank you @spencercw!, yes second option seems like better. threads I am not sure,since I am opening 500+ ports, I need to work around. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: whenever we open a port and call io_service.run() will this create a new thread? or all ports opened here run on the same thread?

Comment: @user1229153 Everything is run on the same thread. `io_service::run()` blocks until it is explicitly stopped or it runs out of work to do. I usually create a separate thread for `run()` so I can continue doing other unrelated processing.

Comment: Thanks @spencercw I understand, though I open 500 ports all will be corresponding to one thread(since all of them are associated to one io_service::run()) untill and unless I isolate them as different threads. Is it advisable to create these many threads?

Comment: I've got no experience with anything that uses nearly that many threads, but I'd say it's probably a bad idea. Start with one thread, and if performance is a problem you can split it up into 2 threads with 250 ports each, or 4 threads with 125 each, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of this

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);

socket.async_connect(endpoint, connectHandler);
```

The `socket` variable is an instance of a single socket, and the call to `async_connect` sets up an asynchronous connect to the location defined by `endpoint`.  You can perform asynchronous reads from and writes to `socket` in a similar fashion, just make sure `io_service.run()` is running in a thread somewhere, or the asynchronous calls (and associated callbacks) won't be executed...

Comment: Thanks for response,Sorry, I did not understand completely, you want me to add this in server class?

Comment: Yes, though in retrospect, you might want to instantiate a listener instead of trying an `async_connect` since this is a server and not a client.  Assuming you already have a listener instantiated in your `server` object, the solution @spencercw proposes is probably closer to what you need.