# use multi-thread to listen more than one port

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm coding a cpp server project.
In this project, I need to listen more than one port. So I am considering using the multi-thread.

I know the boost offers us the multi-thread but I'm not sure if it's suitable for my project.

For example, I have five ports to listen, so I try like this:

```
boost::thread thd1(&fun_listen_port5555);
boost::thread thd2(&fun_listen_port5556);
boost::thread thd3(&fun_listen_port5557);
boost::thread thd4(&fun_listen_port5558);
boost::thread thd5(&fun_listen_port5559);
thd1.join();
thd2.join();
thd3.join();
thd4.join();
thd5.join();
```

If I do like this, may it lose some messages?
May I meet some cases like the thd2 is running while some messages are sending to thd3? In these cases, the messages will lose? If so, what should I do? If not, why?

Comment: This should work fine. Threads that block on IO will be unblocked and eligible for scheduling once the IO is ready. The scheduler will then schedule them as usual. Is there a possibility that you could start losing data if there is too much contention? Of course. But there's always that risk in networked communications. You - or the protocol - need to handle that anyway. So don't worry about it. Creating 5 threads won't be the problem that causes that, by the way, unless your network is blazing fast, your data rate is high, and your processor is unfathomably slow.

Comment: You can also poll/select on all the listening ports at once.

Comment: @Patrick87  thx for you response.

Comment: @StenSoft   how to do that?

Comment: You don't want to poll ports. That's more complicated than using multiple threads. The multi-threaded solution is the proper one.

Comment: @Thomas It depends on what you use for the sockets. If you use Boost then simply put [multiple acceptors/servers into the IO service](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9419873/4538344). If you use POSIX/BSD sockets, then run `select` on the sockets before calling `accept` on the ones that `select` returns as ready-to-read. Contrary to what Rob K writes, it's just as complicated as using multiple threads, maybe even simpler because you don't need to bother with synchronization if you don't process the requests in a thread pool.

Comment: @StenSoft  thx a lot. I have one more question: in fact I'm using the ZeroMQ library. It provides a easy way to select "blocking" or "nonblocking" socket. If I use "nonblocking" mode, it seems that I could also achieve my goal---something like this: `while(true){zmq_recv(self.handle1, &msg.zmq_msg, ZMQ_NONBLOCK);zmq_recv(self.handle2, &msg.zmq_msg, ZMQ_NONBLOCK);}` My question is: what is the difference between using NONBLOCK and using multi-thread with BLOCKING?

Comment: @Thomas ZeroMQ [supports poll](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-poll) and has [a poller in CZMQ](http://api.zeromq.org/czmq3-0:zpoller). Non-blocking without select/poll is not a good way to do it. It won't block so your program will be wasting a lot of CPU asking again and again whether there is anything to receive.